# Проблема с white-space и span, white-space работает неправильно

Tags: html, css

Почему следующий код не переносит элементы после нарушения ними границ родителя?

```css
html,
body {
  background: #202731;
}

.story-item {
  width: 150px;
  margin: 1rem;
  background: red;
}

.story-item-meta>div {
  margin: 0.5rem 0;
}

.story-item-title {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.story-item-ether span {
  padding: 0.2rem;
  margin: 0 0.1rem;
  line-height: 1.2rem;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.item-again {
  background: #81bbea;
  border: 0;
}

.story-item-ether .item-counter {
  background: #ff9800;
}

.story-item-ether {
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="story-items gallery">
  <div class="story-item">
    <div class="story-item-meta">
      <div class="story-item-title">Item 1</div>
      <div class="story-item-desc">Description 1</div>
      <div class="story-item-ether"><span>Cost: 11111</span><span class="item-again">Pick Again</span><span class="item-counter">x3</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

А этот код работает правильно, почему?

```css
html, body {
  background: #202731;
}
body>div {
  width: 170px;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
}
div>div {
  margin: 0.5em;
}
div>span {
  background: white;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>
    <span>Text One</span>
    <span>Text Two</span>
    <span>Text Three</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

JSFiddle: [Вариант 1](https://jsfiddle.net/Telion/8e6cdyq6/1/) | [Вариант 2](https://jsfiddle.net/Telion/8e6cdyq6/2/)

Прошу прощения за код в первом, немного кривоват, но пришлось вытаскивать постепенно пока не свел до минимума.

Answer (score 0):

В общем "сам сказал сам посмеялся". Оказалось при таком расположении `</span><span>` они либо порождают баг в HTML(неужели спустя все это время еще есть баги) либо какая-то очень интересная идея была у разработчиков что порождает подобное поведение. Фикс оказался просто переписать:

```
<div class="story-item-ether"><span>Cost: 11111</span><span class="item-again">Pick Again</span><span class="item-counter">x3</span>
</div>
```

На:

```
<div class="story-item-ether">
    <span>Cost: 11111</span>
    <span class="item-again">Pick Again</span>
    <span class="item-counter">x3</span>
</div>
```

Может кому будет полезно :)

Comment: Сегодня столкнулся с подобным